# Covariance and correlation, and how are they related?

Tags: statistics, correlation, covariance

I get that corellation is the covariance divided by the multiplie variance of the two, uh, things.

What i don't get is why they are divided by the multiplied variance, and why that limits the value to the range -1 : 1.

I suppose i'm really looking for a logical explanation, although a mathematical one wold welcome nontheless.

Comment: Do you know about the Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe no, i just had my first stats lecture today. Lots of algorithms, but not much rationale behind them. Is it relevant, this inequality?

Comment: Sort of; from there the it's clear why the range is $[-1,1]$.  BTW, the covariance is divided by the product of the standard deviations, not by the variances.

Comment: You should read the Wikipedia page entitled "Covariance"

Answer (score 1):

As Michael said, the fact that the correlation coefficient is between $-1$ and $1$ can be shown as a special case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn ).

There is a geometrical interpretation where you see random variables as vectors. Then the covariance is a scalar product, the standard deviations are the norms and the correlation coefficient is the cosine of the angle between the random variables.

But you can also see this as a scaling. Dividing by the standard deviations is a way to put everything on the same scale, so that you can compare variables that have different units for example.